# Discrete Irwin-Hall distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the Irwin-Hall distribution for discrete random variables? That is, if I roll $n$ $k$-sided die and add their sum together, how will the result be distributed?

[John D. Cook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/02/10/rolling-dice-for-normal-samples/) says:

> By using generating functions, you can see that the probability of getting a sum of $k$ spots on the five [six-sided] dice is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of
>
> $(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^5 / 6^5$

But this is all the explanation he gives, and I don't follow.

Additionally, I'm wondering if there is a name for this distribution.

Comment: Check out this paper:
http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf. I think it shows a little more of the derivation.

Comment: So, Eli, did you get squared away on this?